# How do i get single file size?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method:

```
private void Compressions(string zipFile,string sources)
        {
            try
            {
                string zipFileName = zipFile;
                string source = sources;
                string output = @"c:\temp";
                string programFilesX86 = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\Diagnostic Tool\\7z.dll";
                if (File.Exists(programFilesX86))
                {
                    SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(programFilesX86);
                }
                else
                {
                    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\7z.dll";
                    SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(path);
                }
                string programFiles = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\Diagnostic Tool\\7z.dll";
                if (File.Exists(programFiles))
                {
                    SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(programFiles);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (File.Exists(programFilesX86))
                    {
                        SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(programFilesX86);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\7z.dll";
                        SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(path);
                    }
                }
                SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
                compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
                compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
                compressor.TempFolderPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
                string t = Path.Combine(output, zipFileName);
                compressor.CompressDirectory(source, t);

                this.explorerWindow = Process.Start("explorer", String.Format("/select,{0}", t));
                this.TopMost = true;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Zip file error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In the bottom the variable t contain the directory and file name. for example: "c:\temp\test.txt"
I want to get this file name size.

How can i do it ?

Comment: file name size or file size ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For some reason the static class `File` does not contain a `Size(String fileName)` method, instead you need to do it this way:

```
Int64 fileSizeInBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
```

#### Regarding performance:

Don't worry about the `new FileInfo` allocation:

- `FileInfo` does not own any unmanaged resources (i.e. it's not `IDisposable`)
- `FileInfo`'s constructor is cheap: The constructor simply gets the normalized path via `Path.GetFullPath` and performs a `FileIOPermission` - it stores the normalized path as a .NET `String` in an instance field.

Most of the work is inside the `Length` property getter: itself is a wrapper around Win32's `GetFileAttributesEx` - so the operations performed are almost identical to what it would be if it were a `static` utility method.

As the new `FileInfo` object is short-lived it means the GC will collect it quickly as a Generation 0 object. The overhead of a couple of strings (`FileInfo`'s fields) on the heap really is negligible.

Answer (score 3):

Try likes this

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
var size = fi.Length;
Console.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
```

For example

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
var size = fi.Length;
Console.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
```